# Ussing Array Item as Variable Name

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am trying to create a series of variables dynamically e.g. using the value of `item[i]` in a for loop, yet I keep getting thrown an error and am unsure what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Error Message is as follows:

```
var items[i] = post.items[i]; SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

This is my code:

```
items = ["item1", "Item2", "Item3"]         
for (var i = 0;  i < items.length; i++){
    if (post[items[i]]) {
        var items[i] = post.items[i];
        console.log(items[i]);
    } else {
        response.writeHead(400, {"X-Reason": items[i] + "Is Not Set"});
        response.end();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the `var` at that line

Comment: but i am trying to create a new variable, with the name of what ever the value of item[i] is?

Comment: @Mattyboi1670: Then do that, but that's not what that code does. This would create a new variable: `var newVariable = items[i] = post.items[i];` (but that wouldn't be a good idea; after all, you already have `items`).

Comment: @Mattyboi1670 you cannot do that (compute names for variables) in JavaScript. You could use an object and create object properties, however, and those *can* have dynamic names.

Comment: *"I am trying to create a series of variables dynamically..."* That's almost always an anti-pattern. You already have a convenient way to refer to those things (`items`, which you can index into as needed). What purpose would those variables serve?

Comment: Some more error? no declaration of array 'post' and object 'response'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this will do what you want...

```
items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
for (var i = 0;  i < items.length; i++){
    if (post[items[i]]) {
        window[items[i]] = post[items[i]];
    } else {
        response.writeHead(400, {"X-Reason": items[i] + " is Not Set"});
        response.end();
        return;
    }
}
```

Here's a version of the code in a snippet with an included `post` variable so you can see the results...

```js
var post = {
  item1: "This is item 1",
  item3: "This is item 3"
};

var items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];

for (var i = 0;  i < items.length; i++){
  if (post[items[i]]) {
    window[items[i]] = post[items[i]];
  } else {
    console.log("X-Reason:" + items[i] + " is not set");
  }
}

console.log(item1);
console.log(item3);
```

Now the "why" of why you want to do this is the real question you should be asking, but this will do what you've asked.  I suspect that there's probably a much better way to achieve what you really need.

NB. Make sure you're careful about the variable names in the items array.  I changed them all to lowercase in this example - I suggest you do the same.

Comment: thank you for your answer this is what i am looking to do, although given the comments from others on this question i belive i need to rethink my method.

Comment: I agree - glad to hear you do too :)

Answer (score 0):

`var` is used to declare a *new* variable.

You are trying to modify a property of an object stored in an *existing* variable.

Don't use `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `var` from this line:

```
var items[i] = post.items[i];
```

to:

```
items[i] = post.items[i];
```

Property assignment does not use and cannot use variable declaration (`var`).